# Is there a way predict proving times of dough (without experience)?

Tags: baking, yeast, proofing

I make homemade pizza dough and other breads and baked goods quite regularly, but only have started to do so recently. One of the issues I have run into is that recipes always come with their own recommended proving times, some with better results than others.

The issue I have run into is that I want to be able to vary my proving times to be longer or shorter depending on how much time I have between kneading and baking. I have found that longer proving times often lead to nicer flavours (especially with pizza dough), and would like to maximise the time I have. However, I have no idea how to go about this. Without the experience of a seasoned veteran, I don't know how much more or less yeast to add to get the proving time to fit the amount of time I have.

I realise this depends on various factors (heat of the environment, heat of the yeast water, etc.) which make it more unpredictable, but I can keep these factors fairly the same with a constant temperature at all times. Is there a way to tell how much I should vary the yeast, which doesn't consist of me making every recipe I know three times with varying degrees of yeast to see what happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are, although the formulas would vary according to the baked goods you're using.

For pizza, there are working formulas out there, such as [one by TXCraig](https://www.pizzamaking.com/forum/index.php/topic,26831.msg349349.html#msg349349) or [this one](https://www.crustkingdom.com/how-much-yeast-in-pizza-dough/) that calculate the relationship between hydration, temperature, yeast, and proving time.  I personally use the [PizzApp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fisico.pizzapp&hl=en_US) and can attest that it's fairly accurate for any non-extreme combinations (that is, you're kinda on your own with a 72-hour rise).

Presumably there are similar formulas for other baked goods, although pizza is the only one I have personal experience with.